# Check that the local git repo has everything committed and pushed to master

Tags: git

I have some shell script where I want to check one of my git repos. I want to
know if that repos has everything committed and if it is pushed to master.
Before this test I make git fetch to make sure I have the latest changes.

I have found the way to check if the repo has some uncommitted changes:

```
if ! git --work-tree=$HOME/git/project --git-dir=$HOME/git/project/.git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
    echo "Has some changes";
fi
```

But this is not the only thing I need. I also want to make sure that all my
local commits are pushed to master.

What is the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From Mark Longair's great answer I understood that is is possible to check
that local git repo has everything commited and pushed but you need to run 
several commands to do so.

I've written a small script that does all that and write in a frienly way what
has happened.

```
$ is_git_synced ~/git/* --only_errors
Error: path '/home/bessarabov/git/Dancer' has staged changes
Error: path '/home/bessarabov/git/Ubic' has some divergences with remote 'origin'
```

And you can also use exit code to find out if everything is commited and 
pushed or not.

It is at Github: https://github.com/bessarabov/App-IsGitSynced and on CPAN: https://metacpan.org/module/App::IsGitSynced

Comment: Mark Longair's and your's solution seems to miss untracked files. So depending on your purpose the directory may still be considered dirty.

Comment: @vlad-didenko maybe I don't unserstand you, but my solution shows untracked files. Screenshot: http://upload.bessarabov.ru/bessarabov/LbYgP0Daba-oJ5vCDa8Wag8a5H8.png And the code that makes it: https://metacpan.org/source/BESSARABV/App-IsGitSynced-1.0.0/bin/is_git_synced#L84

Comment: Yes, I believe it's me being not clear enough. The "git diff --exit-code && git diff --cached --exit-code" commands do not catch untracked files. Your solution is a large (relatively) script which is hardly an answer to the "easiest way to do" question above - a question which clearly requests a few simple commands. As someone who came here from search I do not see an answer - as going through a considerable perl script is not a (good) answer. May be it is there, but not here :)

Comment: Aha, now I got you. You are right. `git diff --exit-code && git diff --cached --exit-code` does not show info about untracked files. At first I thought that your are saying that neither this 2 commands nor my script `is_git_synced` does not give info about untracked files (and it it is correrect only for 2 command, for my script it is incorrect).

Comment: Yes, I agree that script `is_git_synced` has a disadvantage that it has to be installed, and not "out of the box", but it has the advantage that it is working (and other things are not working) =)

Answer (score 12):

A very easy way to do it would be to simply call

> git push -n

(the "-n" is short for "--dry-run", which means that instead of doing the push, it will instead tell you what it would have pushed)

If it says "Everything up-to-date", then you've already pushed everything to origin.

Alternately, it will give you a list of all the commits that have not yet been pushed to origin.

Or if there are changes on origin that you haven't yet pulled down, then it might complain about potential merges which would be caused by pushing (this duplicates the "has some changes" checking you're already doing)

Comment: If you are on a local branch this gives `Everything up-to-date`. Even if nothing on this branch is pushed.

Comment: However, , does "git push -n" essentially tell us that our local branch is in synch with the corresponding remote branch?

Answer (score 9):

You can check that everything is committed with:

```
git diff --exit-code && git diff --cached --exit-code
```

In a typical configuration, on a successful push to a `master` in `origin`, the remote-tracking branch `origin/master` will be updated.  So, to check if you've pushed all your changes, you can test if:

```
git rev-parse --verify master
```

... is the same as:

```
git rev-parse --verify origin/master
```

Comment: If you want the same function as `--exit-code` without the output, try:
`git diff --quiet && git diff --cached --quiet`

Comment: Incorrect. This won't error if there are uncommitted **new** files in repo.

Answer (score 2):

After a `git fetch`, to check if there are local commits in your branch that have not been pushed to a remote, try this:

```
git diff --exit-code <remote>/<branch>..<branch>
```

This will also tell you if there are commits in the remote that you do not have locally. Note that this is just checking for changes, so if there were to be different commits with identical changes in the remote and the local branch, it is possible that this command would not detect that. In a script, I typically pipe this to `/dev/null` and just check the return status. So, assuming your remote is `origin` and your branch is `master`, the command would look like this:

```
git diff --exit-code origin/master..master > /dev/null
```

As others have suggested, I also use `git diff --exit-code` and `git diff --cached --exit-code` to check for local uncommitted changes.